# AZURE get ip of virtual machine SDK c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm try to get primary IP of virtual machine and I get error `'virtualMachine.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`

I successfully to get IP by use Rest-API in Postman
e.g Postman GET Method

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subid}}/resourceGroups/{{rg}}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/{{vm_name}}?api-version=2020-11-01
```

my code in .Net

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
        clientSecret,
        tenantId,
        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

foreach (var virtualMachine in azure.VirtualMachines.ListByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName))
{
    var name = virtualMachine.Name; 
    var os_type = virtualMachine.OSType; 
    var size = virtualMachine.OSDiskSize;
    var ip = virtualMachine.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress; //Error
}
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: Did you solve this? Would you mind accept my answer for others to refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myVMDotnetProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetVMInfo();

            Console.WriteLine("okok");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static async Task  GetVMInfo()
        {
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User));

            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();

            IVirtualMachines _client = azure.VirtualMachines;
            var list = await _client.ListAsync();

            foreach (var instance in list)
            {
                var name = instance.Name;
                var ip = instance.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress;
                Console.WriteLine("name: " + name + ", ip: " + ip);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the result I test locally:
[image]

Comment: when I tried to make function async the program stopped working when the rest reached the line await _client.ListAsync();
without writing an error
Thanks for help